# How to scanf a string until specific word occurs

Tags: c, arrays, string

Input: I want to be something END. END is is that specific word. I need to store all my words.

```
do
    {
        scanf("%s", row[p]);
        p++;

    }while(strcmp(niz,'END')!=0);
```

Is this the right way ?

Comment: You are scanning data into `row[p]` but your `strcmp` is comparing against `niz` (which is _unmodified_), so your loop will never end. Please post more of your code.

Comment: `'END'` is a multicharacter literal; you probably meant `"END"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
/*Description: How to scanf a string until a specific word occurs*/

int main(){
    char row[6][10];
    int p=0;
    //I want to be something END. ( 6 words for input.)
    printf("Please enter a word.\n");
    /*
    do
    {
        scanf("%s", row[p]);
        p++;

    }while(strcmp(row[p],"END")!=0);
    //Above loop runs forever(or until row runs out of space), because p increments after info is read
    */
    do
    {
        scanf("%s", row[p]);
        p++;

    }while(strcmp(row[p-1],"END")!=0);
    //This loop ends once string just read in from keyboard/user equals "END"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then you need something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * string_toupper( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p ) *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 50 };
    char word[N];
    char tmp[N];

    const char *s = "one two three four end five";

    for ( int offset = 0, pos = 0; 
          sscanf( s + offset, "%s%n", word, &pos ) == 1 && strcmp( string_toupper( strcpy( tmp, word ) ), "END" ) != 0;
          offset += pos )
    {
        puts( word );
    }        
}
```

The program output is

```
one
two
three
four
```

Or something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * string_toupper( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p ) *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 50 };
    char word[N];

    for ( char tmp[N]; scanf( "%s", word ) == 1 && strcmp( string_toupper( strcpy( tmp, word ) ), "END" ) != 0; )  
    {
        puts( word );
    }        
}
```

If to enter

```
one two three four end
```

then the output will be

```
one
two
three
four
```